# Batch reset all iLO passwords via command line

Tags: password, ilo, batch-processing

I would like to batch reset all the iLO passwords on our HP Blade chassis without having to login to each one via the HTTPS website. How can I reset the root and administrator iLO passwords via the SSH command line?

Answer (score 4):

You could set everything in one place from the HP Onboard Administrator.

Through the GUI, the HPOA has password-less access to the individual server ILO interfaces.

Through the CLI, you can `HPONCFG ALL HTTP://some.host.ip/iloconfig.xml` to take care of all devices using one iloconfig.xml file.

Comment: Thanks. I though about using the OA, but it would be a lot of clicking/typing.  I saw a bit about the HPONCFG and XML files, but I didn't have that installed yet. We already use SSH for config/ipmi so I figured a quick script would be easier. If I needed to do more than just change passwords then HPONCFG might be better.

Answer (score 4):

I simplified the script and changed all our iLO passwords with:

```
IPs=`echo 10.0.0.{1..254}`

for ip in $IPs
do
    echo Starting $ip 
    sshpass -p 'PWOLD' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l Administrator $ip "set /map1/accounts1/Administrator password=PWNEW"
done
```

Works like a charm! Many thanx for the inspiring example! (Typo with IPs is corrected!)

Comment: I don't think that `IPs=` line does what you think it does....

Answer (score 3):

I found the fastest way was to use a combination of [SSHPASS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) and the iLO command line interface. The bash script below creates two aliases for using SSHPASS called `oldlogin` and `newlogin` and then uses those to login to the iLO, reset the root account, then login with the new password and reset the administrator account.

```
alias oldlogin="sshpass -p 'OldP@ssword' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l root "
alias newlogin="sshpass -p 'NewP@ssword' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l root "

IPs=`echo 10.0.0.{100..125}` #$IPs is a list of IP addresses from 10.0.0.100-125

for ip in $IPs #Run command to update root login to new password
do
   echo Starting $ip
   oldlogin $ip "set /map1/accounts1/root password=NewP@ssword"
done

for ip in $IPs #Run command to login with new root password and update administrator account
do
   echo Starting $ip
   newlogin $ip "set /map1/accounts1/administrator password=NewP@ssword"
done
```

I saw a reference to `/map1/accounts/` instead of `/map1/accounts1/` but that did not work on my systems. You can login via SSH and use `show map1` to see a list of all available targets. The output should look something like this:

```
root@localhost /usr/bin
$ for ip in $IPs
> do
>    echo Starting $ip
>    oldlogin $ip "set /map1/accounts1/root password=NewP@ssword"
> done
Starting 10.0.0.100
set /map1/accounts1/root password=NewP@ssword
status=0
status_tag=COMMAND COMPLETED

... omitted ...

Starting 10.0.0.125
set /map1/accounts1/root password=NewP@ssword
status=0
status_tag=COMMAND COMPLETED



root@localhost /usr/bin
$ for ip in $IPs 
> do
>    echo Starting $ip
>    newlogin $ip "set /map1/accounts1/administrator password=NewP@ssword"
> done
Starting 10.0.0.100
set /map1/accounts1/administrator password=NewP@ssword
status=0
status_tag=COMMAND COMPLETED

... omitted ...

Starting 10.0.0.125
set /map1/accounts1/administrator password=NewP@ssword
status=0
status_tag=COMMAND COMPLETED
```